# Android Studio sudden appearance of unresolved symbols after pulling from Git

Tags: android, swing, git, tesseract, piccolo

I am new to Android development so I apologize for anything I forget to clarify. I am working on a group project in Android studio, checked out from Git. I previously was able to build the project fine, but after a recent pull I suddenly have many compilation errors coming from the package

projectname\tess two\jni\com_googlecode_tesseract_android\src\java\com\google

It seems that I have a big mess of unresolved symbols, like "cannot resolve symbol (piccolo2d, Color, event, swing), which appear at import statements like these at the top of my classes underneath this project

```
import org.piccolo2d.*;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.Timer;
```

I am wondering what might cause these unresolved symbols. I have tried deleting the project and re-pulling it from Git, re-building the project, etc.

Any help or direction would be great, I realize I did not give a lot of context, mostly because I myself am confused at where these problems could suddenly come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything related to `awt` or `swing` will inevitably fail; those toolkits are not available on Android. Someone or something is accidentally importing symbols from the wrong place. It's probably `android.graphics.Color` you want instead of `java.awt.Color`, etc.

I suspect that if you delete those imports, and then select *Optimize Imports* from the *Code* menu in Android Studio, the correct symbols will be imported.